# Continue Execution of next steps in Serenity Jbehave BDD by capturing failure reason for the failed steps

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jbehave, serenity-bdd

Am currently using Serenity Jbehave BDD framework to Automate my Test Case. I need one information regarding continue execution upon failed step.

I have to continue execution of my next step even though my current step fails in my scenario.

Could you please let me know how can i achieve this by using Serenity Jbehave framework.

Am using Junit and Selenium too.

`ignoreFailureInStories=true` - this configuration will ignore failures at Story level and not at step level. I want the solution at step level.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to continue after a failed step, you should use soft assertions.

Comment: How we can use soft assertions concept in Serenity jbehave framework with Junit ?